# Cancelling a user's subscription through the backend

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have a game created in Unity wherein we have subscriptions enabled for various prized packs. We are storing the details of this subscription in a DB in the backend. I wanted to check if it's possible to cancel the subscriptions through the backend itself - if a particular API exists for Google and Apple stores to do the same for all users belonging to a particular prized pack. Changing the status in our DB for the subscriptions is straightforward, but how do we stop the Google and Apple stores from charging these players on a monthly basis? Or does there exist some way to mark a particular subscription pack as obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On **Google**, you have an [API to cancel a subscription](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#cancel-refund-revoke)
- On **Apple**, such API doesn't exist and the only thing you can do for now, is explaining to your users the different steps to cancel their subscriptions. You can help them with this deeplink: https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions

> Opening this URL launches iTunes or iTunes Store and displays the Manage Subscriptions page where the user can upgrade, downgrade, or cancel their subscription by disabling auto-renew